# Display several nested attributes in Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested, one-to-many

I've been looking for a solution for a few days, in a Rails 4.1 app, so here is my question :

In a Rails app, I have my model User and Adress.

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
       has_many :adresses
       accepts_nested_attributes_for :adresses

 class Adress < ActiveRecord::Base
       belongs_to :user
       accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
```

In my form, I make a form_tag for User, no problem.

But, how I can display to the final user, in a form, 2 adresses fields?

I use `<%= f.fields_for :adress %>` to display one, it's ok. But if I display two forms (so the user can enter 2 adresses) they have both the same name and the request post only keep one.

I read the doc at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

but, still, I don't get it.

Is there a proper way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: A piece of advice - name your classes, variables, methods etc. in English.

Comment: Thanks for your remark, It was ok in my code but I wrote it wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to prepare two addresses in new action, add them to the use and then in the form reneder it with foreach.

I found this kind of solution here : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

Since you have multiple addresses I think foreach is way to go.

Comment: Damn, you make me look so duuuumb! It was right in front of my eyes! Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

So, to help anyone who is noob in Rails and stuck the same way I was :

In your controller :

```
 @user = User.new
 @user.adresses = Adress.new, Adress.new
```

In your view, form :

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :adresses do |a| %>
    <%= wp.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

will print the name field for adress two times.

(thanks again to @NickCatib)

Comment: you can also build your addresses like this `2.times { @user.addresses.build }` instead of `@user.adresses = Adress.new, Adress.new`